# How to execute some code BEFORE logout in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build a custom logout page for a WordPress site.

I disabled the `wp-login.php` using the following `.htaccess` code.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

If you access this you will receive a 403 Forbidden response.

Now I want to execute a function "BEFORE" the user logs out.

```php
function execute_this() {
  wp_logout();
}
```

The thing is all suggestions from the internet is using the following code.

```php
add_action('wp_logout', 'execute_this');
```

But this hook executes "AFTER" successful logout which in my case this can't be done since `wp-login.php` is inaccessible.

That is why I'm trying to log out the user "BEFORE" it goes to the `wp-login.php` file.

Is there a hook/action that triggers this kind of scenario?

I also tried doing such a thing (customizing my logout page with the page that I created):

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'wpse_58453_logout_url' );
function wpse_58453_logout_url( $default )
{
    return plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'logout.php';
}
```

Then in my `logout.php`

```
require_once('../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
wp_logout();
```

I know this is the wrong approach since executing a PHP file directly is never a good idea plus I can't access WordPress hooks when doing something like this.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super experienced with wordpress, but one of the sites that I help maintaining has a custom logout url (`/tp-logout`) and the theme has the following code to perform the logout

```
function tp_custom_logout() {
        if ( is_page( 'tp-logout' ) && is_user_logged_in() ) {
                wp_destroy_current_session();
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                $url_logout = home_url();
                wp_redirect( $url_logout );
                exit();
        }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'tp_custom_logout' );
```

It looks extremely similar to the default WP logout function, so no idea why it was added, but maybe you can add your custom code following this approach.

I would call the function `wp_logout()` to do the actual logout rather than copy the code (and not calling the wp_logout action hooks), to make it a bit more friendly.

Comment: Does this code requires me to create a page/post that has a URL of `/tp-logout`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. For what I read the hook `template_redirect` fires before WP determines what to show.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for this general idea. I have found a workaround with the help of your code with some additional hooks.

Comment: @DavidAngulo - please share your 'workaround' solution in an answer for the benefit of other users thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and found that wp_logout() is pluggable!
So it means that you can write your own wp_logout() function to override WordPress default.
Example:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_logout' ) ) {
/**
 * Log the current user out.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
function wp_logout() {
    remove_sessions() ; // Custom Function Call
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    do_action( 'wp_logout' );
}

function remove_sessions() {
    // Remove custom session and cookie information
}
```

}

You can insert any function you want before you log out.

This example is taken from tutsplus; check this: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-wordpress-pluggable-functions-and-their-usage--wp-30189

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

bro , you can use `auth_cookie_expiration` filter

[see more resources there](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/)

```php
function on_user_loggout($expiration, $user_id)
{
       // { your code }
        return $expiration;
   
}
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'on_user_loggout', 10, 2);
```